# Сортировка вложенного масива на javascript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

**ИСПРАВЛЕНО:**

Есть следующий массив:

```
var mainCategory = [elemen1, element2, element3]
var secondCategory = [elemen4, element5, element6]
var myArray = [ mainCategory, secondCategory]
```

Как отсортировать массив myArray, чтобы выводила в след порядке на странице:

- Главная категория: 1 элемент, 2 элемент, 3 элемент
- Вторая категория: 4 элемент, 5 элемент, 6 элемент

Как это можно реализовать на javascript.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Указанная Вами в вопросе конструкция для переменной `массив` в языке *JavaScript* отсутствует. Запишите её работающем виде.

Comment: я написал на псевдоязыке, просто для наглядности.

Comment: Вы просите код на *JavaScript*, но в то же время используете псевдоязык. Да ещё и с опечатками. Из вопроса не понятно, **что** у Вас в этой структуре. Или Вы думаете, что мы сами должны понять где здесь объекты, где массивы, а где ещё что-то? От содержимого зависит реализация. Два минуса на Вашем вопросе, думаю, достаточно заметный признак того, что с вопросом что-то не так.

Comment: виноват, исправлю

Comment: подправил, в js не силен